# Angular \in symbol?

Tags: symbols

What symbol is this? I can't seem to find it on detexify.[image]

Comment: Where do you find it? It clearly combines < and - together. We also have the upward and downward versions for it, which are variations of `\wedge` and `\vee`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have overlapped two symbols `-` and `<` in arcaic mode :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lehor}{\mathrel{\mathrlap{<}\smash-}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{l}
a<b, X_{a<b}, X_{Y_{a<b}}\\
a\lehor b, X_{a\lehor b}, X_{Y_{a\lehor b}}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @M.Logic You're right. You are free to change my code.

Comment: I update the codes.

Comment: I would remove `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` (not needed) and `\smash` (which isn't really doing anything useful).

Comment: @campa You are free to edit my code. Autorizzato :-)

Answer (score 7):

Two pigeons…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\angin}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\angin@{<}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\angni}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\angin@{>}}}

\newcommand{\angin@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{#2}%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1#2$\cr$\m@th#1-$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A\angin B\angni C_{\angin\angni}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also a good solution.

Answer (score 6):

It is easy enough to make, superimposing a `-` atop a `<`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\mysym{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{l}{}{c}{}{-}{<}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \mysym b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it to work across the math-script styles, then this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\mysym{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{l}{}{c}{}{\SavedStyle-}{\SavedStyle<}}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \mysym b_{c \mysym d_{e \mysym f}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I do the second one that you suggested, this is the result: https://imgur.com/a/MaWcK3Y . The < and - are separated at the first level. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Iain That is odd, as I would suspect the `<` and `-` to both possess the same sidebearings (blank space on sides).  I might have you try two alternatives: extra braces around `-` and `<`, as in `\newcommand\mysym{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{l}{}{c}{}{\SavedStyle{-}}{\SavedStyle{<}}}}}}` or possibly change my left to center alignment, `\newcommand\mysym{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\SavedStyle-}{\SavedStyle<}}}}}`.

Comment: @Iain I might also ask which math font you are using, so I could try to recreate and study it more.  As well as which engine (pdflatex, xelatex, or lualatex)?

Comment: I am using TexpadTex, the default typesetting engine that comes with the Texifier mac application. I have not tried to recreate it using pdflatex or others. As for the math font, whatever is used when importing amsmath and amssymb. I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 6):

From [shapecatcher.com](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/10922), ⪪ is the unicode character `char0x2AAA` corresponding to "Smaller than".

And from the [list of symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) defined by the package [unicode-math](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) it's available with `\smt` if you are using the font XITS Math or STIX Math Two (p. 65).

Answer (score 3):

The ⪪ symbol is `\smt` in `unicode-math`, `stix` or `stix2`, and U+2AAA in Unicode.